# Trying to add multiple properties to Javascript object using a loop

Tags: javascript, object, loops, properties

I hope the day finds you well.

So I have an object with no properties.  I'm trying to add multiple properties to this object using a loop.  Each property added to the loop will appear in the object multiple times depending on how many times the loop runs, with each new property incremented by 1.

So I have something like this:

```
myObject = {  };

for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    myObject.propA + i = foo;
    myObject.propB + i = bar;
};
```

Which I want to yield something like this:

```
myObject.propA0 = foo;
myObject.propB0 = bar;
myObject.propA1 = foo;
myObject.propB2 = bar;
```

Giving a nice stack of objects generated on the fly depending on how many times the loop runs.  But I don't seem to be getting this.  So how exactly do I feed the variable from the loop to the property when it's created and assigned?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try using square bracket notation for the names

```
   myObject['propa' + i] = foo;
```

Comment: This in fact did it, much obliged.

Answer (score 13):

As other users said, you have to use bracket notation to refer to properties by their name strings:

```
myObject['propA' + i] = 'foo';
```

But why don't you use an array of objects, instead of a single object with similar, numbered property names? Something like this:

```
var myArray = [];
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    myArray.push({
        propA: 'foo',
        propB: 'bar'
    });
};
```

This should produce:

```
[
    { propA: 'foo', propB: 'bar'},
    { propA: 'foo', propB: 'bar'}
]
```

It looks way cleaner, in my opinion.

Answer (score 7):

Use the array-access method to set the properties.

```
myObject = {  };

for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    myObject['propA' + i] = foo;
    myObject['propB' + i] = bar;
};
```

Comment: This has proved useful as well, some of the objects in my current project work better as groups of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

you might use

```
object['popA'+i]=...
```

to create a standard property or either use a getter/setter property, in this case you need to use

```
Object.defineProperty(object, *propertyname*, *propertyDescriptor*).
```

The latter gives you more options on the created property.

All details here :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty